# Is there a way to inject a userdefined parameter from method to before method in AbstractBase class

Tags: java, selenium, testng

In method I'm getting my test case name from excel, that is being passed to method using a data provider. I want to pass that Testcase name in @beforemethod( that's defined in different class i.e AbstractBaseclass , Method class is extending this AbstractBaseClass) , Where I have initiated the extent report. and I want to start my report by testcasename.

Is there any way, to pass the testcase name as parameter from method to @beforemethod

Comment: I tried my best to find the answer but couldn't make it, and I changed the architecture of my framework. The other challenge I was getting the object of my hashtable in the method,but when to pass the parameter as @before method was even called before the actual method,  i didn't find it fissile so i change the approach , but i was curious to know is there a way to send a user defined  parameter from method to before method like as we send the object of method as testing injection in before method. Please don't judge just seeing a question

Comment: What else are we supposed to judge by other than just the question? That's all you've given us to judge. The point is that you should try several things during your investigation. If you try all you can think of and still can't solve the problem, *then* you post a question on SO listing the various things you've tried. Your question shows no research effort at all. If you've done some, show your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you do it. TestNG lets you inject an `Object[]` array into the `@BeforeMethod` annotated method. When TestNG sees an object array, it natively injects the parameters that are about to be passed to a data driven `@Test` method. Refer [this](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/Allowed-parameters-injection-in-methods) TestNG wiki page to learn more about what are all allowed by TestNG as part of native injection.

Here's how your base class can look like :

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

public class AbstractBaseClass {
    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(Object[] parameters) {
        //Here we are assuming that the testname will always be the first parameter
        //in the 1D array that gets sent for every iteration of @Test method
        if (parameters != null && parameters.length >= 1) {
            String testname = parameters[0].toString();
            System.out.println("Test name obtained in beforeMethod() " + testname);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how your test class can look like

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClass extends AbstractBaseClass {
    @Test(dataProvider = "getData")
    public void testMethod(String testname, int count) {
        Assert.assertNotNull(testname);
        Assert.assertTrue(count > 0);
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {"LoginTestCase", 100},
                {"ComposeMailTestcase", 200}
        };
    }
}
```

This way you can get hold of your test name in your base class itself, even if its being fed in via a data provider.

And as always please ensure you are on **TestNG 6.11** (which as of today July 20, 2017 is the latest released version of TestNG)

Comment: Thank u so much !! I'll try this tomorrow when inwill go back to office, i have another doubt what if my test class has hastable as an argument ?? Will that approach work and how i will get that particular key , value pair in before method that i have used as a test case name. If u want to get it understand by example i will mention that tomorrow

Comment: It would work the same way. You would still get an `Object[]` array as a parameter in your `@BeforeMethod` annotated method and you would just need to figure out which of the `Object[]` index represents your `Map` and then work with it. There is no change in the approach. Also please help accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Thanks a tone krishnan !!